# ViewPager remove fragments from backStack

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm using ViewPager in this way:

```
Tab 1
Tab 2
Tab 3 -> Fragment NewEvents -> FragmentEventProfile
```

While I'm getting to the FragmentHostProfile, I want to remove all the other fragments from backStack so when I hit the back button I don't go neither to "FragmentEvents" or "Tab 3";
How do I do this so my ViewPager knows that FragmentHostProfile is his Tab 3 now?
Thank you.

Here's how I replace fragments in Tab3:

```
FragmentTransaction trans = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            trans.replace(R.id.loginContainer, new FragmentHostProfile().newInstance(), "Login-Profile");
            trans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            trans.addToBackStack(null);
            trans.commit();
```

Comment: ViewPager passes position value within each windows transition , if you mean that you are adding fragments to your third ViewPager and using getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(...) make sure to use .replace(..) instead

Comment: How do I make so when I hit BackButton from last fragment it won't do anything?

Comment: Please clarify your question by adding some code sample

Comment: exact what behavior do you want when you press back button on FragmentEventProfile?

Comment: Hey guys I just added code I'm replacing fragments with.
I want the BackButton not take user to previous fragment unless I press LogOut button.